# Can we deploy spring micro services on AWS Lambda?

Tags: spring-boot, aws-lambda, microservices

Is it recommended to deploy spring micro services on Lambda. I have recently deployed a sample spring boot app returning a sample data from AWS RDS Oracle DB on Lambda, Just analyzing the possibility if we could deploy two micro services in different Lambda functions and configure them using API gateway.

I am entirely new to it and trying to understand if Lambda can really support micro services patterns like Service discovery/Circuit breaker or Saga patterns if I deploy two or more services on different lambda functions. Would Lambda be used for such scenarios in Real Time ?

Can anyone help me if there would be limitations other than package/payload size limit or timeout limitations ?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

If you use java for serverless application like AWS lambdas I would recommend for looking a framework which supports Ahead-of-Time compilation which will boost a lot your application start. If your application is not bit it will be very easy to be rewritten with Micronaut (very similar to Spring boot development)

For instance have a look at Micronaut, Quarkus using with Graalvm. Spring Boot is not the best option using with directly with AWS lambdas, it is big package size + really a lot of initial time, not good for API services.

Target of max package sizes of 25 MB for small cold start with adjustable memory starting from 256MB, with spring boot this is not doable.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are referring to [Spring Boot Cloud Functions](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-function/reference/html/spring-cloud-function.html#_getting_started) that's exactly they were made for.

Google Cloud Functions already have an [Alpha product](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-function/reference/html/gcp.html) for running Java functions.

AWS Lambda seems to have support for this [as well](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-function).

In case you simply wrote a Spring Boot app with embedded Tomcat that you packaged in a Docker container which you're spinning up on demand, beware that cold start can be an issue, especially with the overhead of the Tomcat.

Comment: Can we use spring cloud functions along with @RestController and its mappings ? I think if we use Supplier/Function/Supplier we could only write business logic in apply() method only right ?

Comment: @Prasanna I added link to Baeldung which basically confirms what you're saying. Consider FaaS (= Lambda) as one single task. What you're looking for - circuit breaker/service discovery - would have to live in a layer above, therefore OUTSIDE of your functions' logic.